# How to make the function called by @submit work?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

```html
<!--html-->
<div id="vvv">
    <form action="#">
        <input required type="text">
        <input type="submit"  @submit="func">
    </form>
</div>
```

```js
// js
vvv = new Vue({
    el: '#vvv',
    methods: {
        func(){
            console.log(11111111111111)
        }
    }
})
```

#### How to make the function called by `@submit` work?

I need use the default `submit` action to inspect if all required fields have been filled. And after that, i wanna call my own submit function which set by `@submit` to post form data.

But, i find the function set by `@submit` is not be allowed to call.

What's wrong with my code? Or, if this action really not be allowed? And how can i realize my requirement?

Comment: I think you have to call `func` like `func()` ==> `@submit="func()"`, but I'm not sure

Comment: Try `@submit.prevent.stop="func"`

Comment: @Samathingamajig thank you, but that's not the point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling the function from form tag

```
<!--html-->
<div id="vvv">
    <form action="#" @submit.prevent="func" >
        <input required type="text">
        <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to do some custom validations, `Vue` makes it easy to track the state in real time. In the example I threw together below, you can see how a few different fields are simply validated to not be empty.

This is something you would build on, of course, to make more advanced validations, but hopefully it illustrates the concept. Then, you can use whatever method on whatever element you want to submit your form data!

https://codepen.io/barneychampaign/pen/JjKxymg